# Add sparkle effect with magnificpopup script

Tags: jquery, html, css, magnific-popup

I'm using magnificPopup script for my gallery page.

[magnificPopup-Github](https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup)

And here is the sparkle effect

[Sparkle Effect](https://github.com/simeydotme/jQuery-canvas-sparkles)

Now I just want to add sparkle effect to each gallery image when the hover. It's working fine. But I need to add that same sparkle effect to image thumbnail mode.

[Thumb image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4I8A.png)

This is my code for normal image hover mode.

```
<div class="cards-row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
      <a href="/images/Cards/alien-back.jpg" data-effect="mfp-3d-unfold">
        <div class="sparkley">
          <img src="/images/Cards/alien-front.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
```

As you can see it, front image wrap with sparkley class. I used bit jquery for wrapping that back image.

```
$( "figure" ).addClass( "sparkley" );
```

It's not working at all. I've added another class with hover effect but it worked. I'm guessing that the sparkley effect using mouseover jquery function not hover? I'm stuck here.

Comment: Are you using [this](https://github.com/simeydotme/jQuery-canvas-sparkles)?

Comment: I dont think just by adding the class you will be able to get your plugin working.. as @RaphaelSchweikert pointed if that the stuff you are using then you are missing the binding of the plugin to your element using jquery.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert Yes. That's the plugin I'm using.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you call the `magnificPopup` method?

Comment: Here it is 
http://codepen.io/jayDilz/pen/ONjORo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you’d do something like this:

```
$('#gallery').magnificPopup({
  […],
  callbacks: {
    open: function() {
      this.contentContainer.find('figure').sparkle();
    },
    resize: function() {
      this.contentContainer.find('figure').trigger('resize.sparkle');
    }
});
```

This will initialize the sparkle plugin only after opening the gallery popup (when the `open` callback is called) and instruct it to re-layout when its size has changed.

This assumes you have the default markup for the popup that Magnific Popup generates for you. If you use custom markup for the sparkle content, use some element other than `<figure>`.

Also, maybe you want to wrap the `<img>` in some container and use that instead of the `<figure>` so that the sparkle effect is only over the image and not the whole popup container.

```js
/**
 * Overlay for images (gallery)
 *
 * @param {string} theme
 */
var openGallery = function(theme) {
};

// Galleries
$('ul.magnific-gallery').magnificPopup({
  delegate: '> li > a',
  type: 'image',
  gallery: {
    enabled: true
  },
  callbacks: {
    open: function() {
      var $spark = this.contentContainer.find('figure');
      $spark.sparkle();
      
      // The code below can be used to start the effect immediately
      $spark.off("mouseover.sparkle")
        .off("mouseout.sparkle")
        .off("focus.sparkle")
        .off("blur.sparkle")
        .trigger("start.sparkle");
    },
    resize: function() {
      this.contentContainer.find('figure').trigger('resize.sparkle');
    }
  },
});
```

```css
.magnific-gallery img {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/simeydotme/jQuery-canvas-sparkles/master/dist/jquery-canvas-sparkles.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<ul class="magnific-gallery">
  <li>
    <a href="http://i1232.photobucket.com/albums/ff372/Marcin_Gil/magnific%20example/flower1.jpg" title="Etiam ullamcorper.">
      <img src="http://i1232.photobucket.com/albums/ff372/Marcin_Gil/magnific%20example/flower1.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://i1232.photobucket.com/albums/ff372/Marcin_Gil/magnific%20example/flower2.jpg" title="Cum sociis natoque penatibus." data-description="Estibulum id, eleifend justo vel bibendum sapien massa ac turpis faucibus orci luctus non, consectetuer lobortis quis, varius in, purus. Integer ultrices posuere cubilia.">
      <img src="http://i1232.photobucket.com/albums/ff372/Marcin_Gil/magnific%20example/flower2.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
  </li>
   <li>
    <a href="http://i1232.photobucket.com/albums/ff372/Marcin_Gil/magnific%20example/flower3.jpg" title="Maecenas malesuada.">
      <img src="http://i1232.photobucket.com/albums/ff372/Marcin_Gil/magnific%20example/flower3.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
  </li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://i1232.photobucket.com/albums/ff372/Marcin_Gil/magnific%20example/flower4.jpg" title="Vestibulum dapibus, mauris nec malesuada fames ac turpis velit, rhoncus eu, luctus et interdum adipiscing wisi." data-description="Vestibulum dapibus, mauris nec malesuada fames ac turpis velit, rhoncus eu, luctus et interdum adipiscing wisi.">
      <img src="http://i1232.photobucket.com/albums/ff372/Marcin_Gil/magnific%20example/flower4.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In the snippet, I have made the sparkles start immediately by removing the hover events and triggering `"start.sparkle"` manually in the `open` callback:

```
this.contentContainer.find('figure')
  .off("mouseover.sparkle")
  .off("mouseout.sparkle")
  .off("focus.sparkle")
  .off("blur.sparkle")
  .trigger("start.sparkle");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working fine now. If you can explain bit your code, that would be great.